# Jetpack Compose - Detect when LazyColumn's scroll position is at the first index

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to have a **Scroll back to top button** for my `LazyColumn`. I successfully made the button work. But I want it to not be visible if I'm already at the top of the `LazyColumn`. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Comment: Have you tried the `firstVisibleItemIndex` on the `LazyListState` that you pass to your `LazyColumn`? It should give you the index of the first item that is visible within your list. If you want more information then you can query `layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo` which gives you information on all the visible items within your list.

Comment: @Rafsanjani Yeah, It was that. Something got me confused about the LazyListState's properties (see the answers' comments). I think my mind is not fully awake in the morning.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`LazyColumn` has `state` property, and if you pass your custom value instead of the default one, you can react on the state changes.

To prevent redundant recompositions, in such cases [`derivedStateOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#derivedStateOf(kotlin.Function0)) should be used: it'll trigger recomposition only when the produced result, based on other state variables, is changed:

```kotlin
Box {
    val state = rememberLazyListState()
    LazyColumn(state = state) {
        // ...
    }
    val firstItemVisible by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            state.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0
        }
    }
    if (!firstItemVisible) {
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good answer. (But I had to accept the first answer) I don't know why someone downvoted you. When I was looking at the properties of the LazyListState, I was wondering why aren't those States but primitives. How would Compose know when to update the Composables? I forgot that LazyListState is a state itself (lol).

Comment: @daniyelp if you add logs, you'll see that the accepted answer triggers recomposition during scrolling. Compose uses `State` and `MutableState` wrappers to track changes. In my sample `derivedStateOf` is checking result of `state.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0` each time `state` is changed, and only triggers recomposition when it's not the same. You can learn more about state in Compose 
in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles.

Comment: @daniyelp if a state variable is used directly during view building, changing this state will trigger recomposition.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is better. This is indeed a case in which derviedStateOf should be used. Now I think that in general the better answer should be accepted, regardless of the time difference. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47448/allow-me-to-accept-an-answer-immediately)

Comment: I think I know decently much about `State` and how to use it. In today's morning I was unusually tired xd.

Answer (score 3):

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        startActivity(intent)

        setContent {
            val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
            val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                if (scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0) {
                    Button(onClick = {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            scrollState.scrollToItem(0)
                        }
                    }, enabled = scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0) {
                        Text("Scroll to top")
                    }
                }

                LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), state = scrollState) {
                    items(MutableList(100) { it }) { i ->
                        Text(i.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, I was looking at the lazyListState's primitives and I was asking myself why aren't these States? How would the composable know when to recompose itself? I forgot that lazyListState handles that.